# Recieving ZoneAwarePromise instead of regular promise in Angular 6

Tags: angular

I am using algoliasearch library in my Angular 6 application.

When i execute the following code in Angular 6 i receive a ZoneAwarePromise object instead of a normal promise

[image]

The code looks something like this:

```
 fetchSingleUser(objectID) {
        const options = environment.algolia;
        const client = algoliasearch(options.appId, options.apiKey);
        this.index = client.initIndex(options.indexName);
        return this.index.getObject(objectID)

    }
```

Again to be clear, the connection to Algolia works fine. However instead of receiving a normal promise I receive something called ZoneAwarePromise. I am not sure how to handle this ?